# Command line tool to analyze amount of motion in video file

Tags: linux, video, data-analysis

I am looking for a command-line-ready tool that will work on Linux which will be able to give me a value (or small set of values) which represent the amount of motion present in a given video file.

For example a 1 minute video of an empty room might come back with `0` (or close to it). A tripod shot of a person speaking might come back with `50`. And a hand held-shot where the videographer is frantically swinging the camera around might come back with `100`.

The ultimate goal of this would be to easily identify the segments of footage from a wall-mounted security camera where people, cars, or animals appear.

I would be willing to entertain writing my own script in python if the principles used are simple enough.

Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: You might look at what `motion` does with regard to detecting ... motion... in a webcam feed or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.VLC has a motion detection filter that you can try by accessing: Tools -> Effects and Filters -> Video Effects -> Advanced -> Motion Detect.

Check [this](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=89563#p340619) out for CLI tools.

2.DVR-Scan is a cross-platform command-line (CLI) application that automatically detects motion events in video files (e.g. security camera footage). 
It's open-source, written in Python, and based on Numpy and OpenCV.

https://github.com/Breakthrough/DVR-Scan

Comment: DVR-Scan looks like exactly what I am looking for. Thanks